# Mapping Entities to DTOs in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dto, orm

In a recent project my backend architecture consists of

- `Repositories` (talking to database)
- `Services` (handling business logic)
- `Controllers` (handling incoming REST calls and providing according responses to the client)

I introduced `DTO` classes for representing the data that is returned by the controllers when a client calls a REST route. Because the services work with `Entities`, I need to somehow map those to my `DTO`s. The `DTO`s contain most of the properties of the according `Entity`, but can define additional properties as well.

First of all, I have the following `Entities`:

**Image Entity**

```js
@Entity()
export class Image {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne(...)
    parentFolder: Folder;

    @ManyToMany(...)
    tags: Tag[];
}
```

**Tag Entity**

```js
@Entity()
export class Tag {
    id: number;
    label: string;

    @ManyToMany(...)
    images: Image[];
}
```

As you can see, there are also some relations (ManyToOne, ManyToMany), so my `Entities` contain references to other `Entities`. Same for according `DTO`s.

Next, you can see my shortened `ImageController`. In the method `findOne`, a service is asked to look for an `Entity` with given id in the database.

**Image Controller**

```js
@Controller('image')
export class ImageController {
    constructor(
        private readonly imageService: ImageService,
        private readonly imageEntityToDtoMapper: ImageEntityToDtoMapper
    ) { }

    @Get(':id')
    async findOne(@Param('id') id): Promise<ImageDto> {
        const image: Image = await this.imageService.findOne(id);
        return this.imageEntityToDtoMapper.map(image);
    }
}
```

In order to let the controller return a `DTO`, the result is mapped by an `ImageEntityToDtoMapper`.

**ImageEntityToDtoMapper**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ImageEntityToDtoMapper {
    constructor(
        private readonly folderService: FolderService,
        private readonly folderEntityToDtoMapper: FolderEntityToDtoMapper,
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => TagEntityToDtoMapper))
        private readonly tagEntityToDtoMapper: TagEntityToDtoMapper
    ) { }

    async map(entity: Image): Promise<ImageDto> {
        if (entity) {
            const parentFolderPath = await this.folderService.buildPathByFolderId(entity.parentFolder.id);
            const absolutePath = `${parentFolderPath}${path.sep}${entity.name}`;

            const dto = new ImageDto();
            dto.id = entity.id;
            dto.name = entity.name;
            dto.absolutePath = absolutePath;
            dto.parentFolder = await this.folderEntityToDtoMapper.map(entity.parentFolder);
            dto.tags = await this.tagEntityToDtoMapper.mapAll(entity.tags);
            return dto;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my questions, all regarding `ImageEntityToDtoMapper`:

1. Beside simply mapping properties `id` and `name` from one class to the other, I'm also "calculating" `absolutePath`, which is not contained in the original `Entity`, but only in `DTO`. Is this mapper class the correct place for that?

   Furthermore, for that reason I need to inject the `FolderService` to the mapper, which seems not quite correct to me...
2. Because of the Image`Entities`' relations to `Folder` and `Tag`, I need to call their mapper classes from the `ImageEntityToDtoMapper`. Is this the correct way to do it?
3. Because I need to inject other `Entities`' mappers, I have a circular dependency between `ImageEntityToDtoMapper` and `TagEntityToDtoMapper`. And in my whole project, I have more cases where multiple mappers depend on each other.

   Although the library ([NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/)) I'm using offers a way to handle this by using `forwardRef`, I would like to avoid those circular dependencies. Could you think of any possibility?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: There is one article which explains these issues much better: 
https://nartc.netlify.app/blogs/introduction-to-automapper-typescript/
Check if this works for you.